# QGIS SRS storage

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I need to send to my jobmate a pack of local SRS parameters. I already have them in my QGIS User Coordinate systems. Can i just send a folder or, maybe, a file, witch contains all of my custom Coordinate systems? There are no description according storing SRS parameters in QGIS user manual. I don't want to send a pack of WKT strings for each CS.